# How to capture invalid dates in input type="date" ? which event to trigger?

Tags: angular, datepicker

I am implementing HTML5 native date picker input that allows user to either select date from datepicker or enter date manually

When user enters invalid dates like `02/31/2022` or `04/31/1999`, input us not triggering any events.

Here's my code, I have

```
<input
   type="date"
   (change)="onChange($event.target.value)"
   (keydown)="onKeydown($event.target.value)"
   (input)="onInput($event.target.value)"`
   (invalid)="onInvalid($event.target.value)"
   [min]="minValidDate$"
   [max]="maxValidDate$"
   id="dateInput" />
```

I am working in Angular, so onEvent listeners looks little different. I have tried 4 event here `change,input` and `keydown` all 3 event gives target value for all valid date inputs. I could not make the `invalid` event working.

I would like to fire the `Invalid Date` validation from my angular code when user enters any invalid dates.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Is there any textbox event that gives invalid date input in `textbox.val`?

Comment: I noticed extra char on fifth line (input)="onInput($event.target.value)"`  <--. Maybe this is the issue.

Comment: Yeah, that's typo while pasting question here. With very low credit, I guess I am unable to see the edit link in my question. However, that is not the reason of this issue for sure.